# Converting dataframe object to date using to_datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe, merge

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
    date        id
0   2014-01-01  11000929
1   2014-01-01  11000190
2   2014-01-01  11000216
3   2014-01-01  11000822
4   2014-01-01  11000971
5   2014-01-01  11000721
6   2014-01-01  11000970
7   2014-01-01  11000574
8   2014-01-01  11000967
9   2014-01-01  11000172
10  2014-01-01  11000208
11  2014-01-01  11000966
12  2014-01-01  11000344
13  2014-01-01  11000965
14  2014-01-01  11000935
15  2014-01-01  11000964
16  2014-01-01  11000741
17  2014-01-01  11000868
18  2014-01-01  11000035
19  2014-01-01  11000203
20  2014-01-02  11000574
```

as you can see there is a lot of duplciate date times for different products, I will merge this table with another table which requires me to convert date column, which is currently and object, to datetime64[ns].

I tried

```
df_date_id.date = pd.to_datetime(df_date_id.date)
```

but I end up having the error:

```
TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'> is not convertible to datetime
```

p.s: the table I am going to merge with looks like this:

```
    date        id          score
0   2014-01-01  11000035    75
1   2014-01-02  11000035    84
2   2014-01-03  11000035    55
```

so date format of both tables looks the same to me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think is necessary convert period to datetimes with [`to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html):

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.to_timestamp()
print (df['date'].dtypes)
datetime64[ns]
```

Another solution is convert column in another `DataFrame` to periods like:

```
df2['date'] = df2['date'].dt.to_period('d')
```

Comment: To merge the dataframes, converting to datetime isn't necessary. It will still work if the date column is `str`, no ?

Comment: @YOLO - I think problem here is different dtypes - datimes and periods, for same one is necessary converting.

Comment: When I checked the datatypes using dtypes, one was object and other one was datetime64[ns].
Your alternative solution worked better for me. Thank you

Comment: @crinix - yes, problem is `object` should be string, period, so only way for check it is check type of one value by  `print (type(df.loc[0, 'date']))`

Comment: as always when i look something up and jexrael has given an answer its right! Top tip, do what ever he suggests, he is a genius!

Comment: @ARob4 - No, I dont think you are right. There are many better pandas guy like unutbu, jeff, coldspeed, jpp, edchum and many others. Many of then participate for new versions of pandas, so not time to contribute in SO. :)

Answer (score 3):

Works for me by specifying the format:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y-%M-%d')

     date                 id
0 2014-01-01 00:01:00  11000929
1 2014-01-01 00:01:00  11000190
2 2014-01-01 00:01:00  11000216
3 2014-01-01 00:01:00  11000822
4 2014-01-01 00:01:00  11000971
```

If not try:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str), format='%Y-%M-%d')
```

Comment: Specifying the format worked in terms of converting the format however caused other problems since hour info showed up, so I followed jezrael's solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was curious why this answer would provide minute info. After trying I realize that `%M` is Minute as a zero-padded decimal number instead of month. `%Y-%m-%d` should be used instead.